# Firebase data is not updated properly

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem : the data always get updated into 4350, 
And the alert keep's pop-up-ing.

The code:

```
// Get no antrian function
function getNoAntri(tipe, username, name) {
  // Define firebase URL
  var faskesRef = new Firebase("https://cepatsembuh.firebaseio.com/" + tipe + "/faskes/" + username);

  // Log firebase URL
  console.log('Url :' + "https://cepatsembuh.firebaseio.com/" + tipe + "/faskes/" + username);

  // Warn user that this fiture need internet
    alert('Fitur ini membutuhkan internet untuk mengambil data');

  // Confirmation
  alert("Mohon konfirmasi ulang");
  var nama = prompt("Masukan nama"),
  nik = prompt("Masukan NIK:");
  if (nama != "" || nik.length != 16) {
    var pasien = new Firebase("https://cepatsembuh.firebaseio.com/" + tipe + '/pasien/');
    // Initialize data
    faskesRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      // Update variables
      var data = snapshot.val().antrian,
      one = 1,
      sum = data + one;

      // Update nomor antrian
      faskesRef.update({
        nama: name,
        antrian: sum
      });

      // Print data
      alert('No antrian: ' + snapshot.val().antrian);

      // Push data to firebase
      pasien.push().set({
        nama: nama,
        nomor_antrian: snapshot.val().antrian
      })
    });
  } else {
    // Error message
    alert("Input anda tidak valid. \n Anda tidak bisa mendapatkan nomor antrian");
  }
}
```

I've try many ways, but the code still never work. 
Sorry If I doesn't ask a proper question btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what your problem is, but an educated guess is that it boils down to this fragment of your code:

```
// Push input value to firebase
pasien.push().set({
  nama: nama,
  nik: nik,
  lokasi: lokasi
});

window.location.href = 'option/' + 'available.html';
```

Writing data to Firebase is an asynchronous operation. Calling `set()` *starts* that operation, but by the time the set `window.location`, the write operation won't be done yet.

The solution is to wait for the write operation to complete before navigating away, which you can do by using a [Firebase completion listener](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback):

```
// Push input value to firebase
pasien.push().set({
  nama: nama,
  nik: nik,
  lokasi: lokasi
}, function(error) {
    if (!error) {
        window.location.href = 'option/' + 'available.html';
    }
    else {
        // TODO: handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry frank, It looks like I write the wrong code. 
The right code is written above.